# Spring Boot default proxying mechanism

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, proxy

Recently i found [spring documentation page](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch08s06.html) that says:

> Spring AOP uses either JDK dynamic proxies or CGLIB to create the proxy for a given target object. (JDK dynamic proxies are preferred whenever you have a choice).
>
> If the target object to be proxied implements at least one interface then a JDK dynamic proxy will be used.

But it doesn't seem to be the case in my application. I wanted to write a small benchmark to compare the performance of both types of proxying.

There are two similar classes. Both have one method annotated with the `@Transactional` annotation. One class implements the interface and the other does not:

```
@Service
public class Cglib {
    @Transactional
    public void method() {}
}
```

```
public interface Dynamic {
    void method();
}
```

```
@Service
public class DynamicImpl implements Dynamic {
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void method() {}
}
```

And based on the documentation for the first class, a CGLIB proxy should be created, and for the second, a JDK dynamic proxy.

But in my case CGLIB was used for both classes:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Runner implements ApplicationRunner {
    private final Cglib cglib;
    private final Dynamic dynamic;

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) {
        System.out.println(cglib.getClass());
        System.out.println(dynamic.getClass());
    }
}
```

```
class com.example.demo.proxy.cglib.Cglib$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$767ff22
class com.example.demo.proxy.dynamic.DynamicImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$20a564d6
```

There are no additional configurations in the application. Only `@SpringBootApplication` class generated via spring initializr

Am I doing something wrong? The code was run on Spring Boot 2.7.2 and JDK 17.

Comment: The documentation is for plain Spring **not** for Spring Boot. The latter automatically forces/enables always class based proxies.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is due to [spring-boot autoconfiguation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/transaction/TransactionAutoConfiguration.java#L99):

```java
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@ConditionalOnBean(TransactionManager.class)
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(AbstractTransactionManagementConfiguration.class)
public static class EnableTransactionManagementConfiguration {

    @Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
    @EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass = false)
    @ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "spring.aop", name = "proxy-target-class", havingValue = "false")
    public static class JdkDynamicAutoProxyConfiguration {
    }

    @Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
    @EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass = true)
    @ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "spring.aop", name = "proxy-target-class", havingValue = "true",
                matchIfMissing = true)
    public static class CglibAutoProxyConfiguration {
    }
}
```

it turns `@EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass = true)` (*Indicate whether subclass-based (CGLIB) proxies are to be created (true) as opposed to standard Java interface-based proxies (false)*) on when the configuration property `spring.aop.proxy-target-class` is not set (`matchIfMissing = true`)

Comment: Yes, it looks like the spring boot configuration includes this behavior. Found a [github issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5423) that describes the reason for such a solution. It would be great to know how to turn it off.

Comment: @vszholobov  in general specifying `spring.aop.proxy-target-class=false`  or disabling `TransactionAutoConfiguration` autoconfiguration and writing own configuration should help, however there are some related discussions on that topic:  https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12194

Comment: Specifying `spring.aop.proxy-target-class=false` solved the problem. Now the JDK dynamic proxy is used for the second class