# Spring Bean Config

Tags: java, xml, spring

I'm learning the bean AOP with Annotation and xml config but Spring does not create the beans.

Interface

```
package com.spring.studying.SpringAop.FrameworkService.AspectJAnnotation;

public interface Artist {
    void perform();
}
```

Guitar Class

```
package com.spring.studying.SpringAop.FrameworkService.AspectJAnnotation;


import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("grammyGuitarist")
public class GrammyGuitarist implements Artist{

    @Override
    public void perform() {
        System.out.println("Start to play guitar");
    }

    public void playGuitar(String brand)
    {
        System.out.println("Get Guitar "+brand);
    }
    public void rest()
    {
        System.out.println("zzZZ!!!!");
    }
}
```

Documentarist

```
package com.spring.studying.SpringAop.FrameworkService.AspectJAnnotation;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component(value="documentaries")
public class Documentarist {
    private GrammyGuitarist guitarist;
    public void executed()
    {
        guitarist.playGuitar("LakeWood");
        guitarist.perform();
        guitarist.rest();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setGuitarist(GrammyGuitarist guitarist) {
        this.guitarist = guitarist;
    }
}
```

Advice Class

```
package com.spring.studying.SpringAop.FrameworkService.AspectJAnnotation;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("annotatedAdvice")
@Aspect
public class AnnotatedAdvice {
    @Pointcut("execution(* rest*(..)) && args(brand)")
    public void restExecution(String brand)
    {

    }

    @Pointcut("bean(grammyGuitarist)")
    public void isGrammyGuitarist()
    {

    }

    @Before("restExecution(brand) && isGrammyGuitarist")
    public void simpleBeforeAdvice(JoinPoint joinPoint , String brand)
    {
        System.out.println("Before Advice processing");
        System.out.println("Playing guitar :" + brand);
        System.out.println("Executing :"+ joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName() +" "+joinPoint.getSignature().getName());

    }

}
```

Demo Class

```
package com.spring.studying.SpringAop.FrameworkService.AspectJAnnotation;

import org.springframework.context.support.GenericXmlApplicationContext;

import java.util.Arrays;


public class AspectJAnnotationDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenericXmlApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
        ctx.load("aop-aspectj-annotation-style.xml");
        ctx.refresh();
        Arrays.stream(ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames()).forEach(System.out::println);
        Documentarist documentarist = ctx.getBean("documentaries",Documentarist.class);
        documentarist.executed();
    }
}
```

My Xml Config File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
    ">
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.studying.SpringAop"/>


    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
</beans>
```

None of my beans were created just 6 default beans from spring.

I have try to create bean with  tag and it worked fine . Just don't know why my code did not work with the annotation.

Comment: Stop using the outdated xml configuration in spring. Use the java configuration instead

Comment: i tried both of them for learning :D

Comment: Why you learn outdated things?

Comment: I need to upgrade an old project

Answer (score 1):

`restExecution` `@Pointcut` is wrong, because `rest` method of `GrammyGuitarist` doesn't take any arguments. `playGuitar` method takes `brand` argument, so you need to change your pointcut a bit:

```
@Component("annotatedAdvice")
@Aspect
public class AnnotatedAdvice {
    @Pointcut("execution(* play*(..)) && args(brand)")
    public void playExecution(String brand) {

    }

    @Pointcut("bean(grammyGuitarist)")
    public void isGrammyGuitarist() {

    }

    @Before("playExecution(brand) && isGrammyGuitarist()")
    public void simpleBeforeAdvice(JoinPoint joinPoint, String brand) {
        System.out.println("Before Advice processing");
        System.out.println("Playing guitar :" + brand);
        System.out.println("Executing :" + joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName() + " " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());

    }
}
```

When you do this, aspects will indeed be created, but you will start getting exceptions:

```
Bean named 'grammyGuitarist' is expected to be of type 'com.example.demo.aspect.GrammyGuitarist' but was actually of type 'jdk.proxy2.$Proxy14'
```

This is because `GrammyGuitarist` implements an interface, and [in this case `Spring AOP` uses JDK dynamic proxies](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch08s06.html)

The simplest solution would be to force the use of a CGLIB proxy. To do this, you need to add an annotation above the aspect:

```
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
```

After that, the program will give the expected result:

```
annotatedAdvice
documentaries
grammyGuitarist
org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator
Before Advice processing
Playing guitar :LakeWood
Executing :com.example.demo.aspect.GrammyGuitarist playGuitar
Get Guitar LakeWood
Start to play guitar
zzZZ!!!!
```

In Spring Boot, CGLIB enforcement is enabled by default. Check [this question for better understanding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73231258/spring-boot-default-proxying-mechanism)

Comment: I think the cglib can work with my GrammyGuitarist class. The JDK will create an instance that implement the Singer interface but my Guitarist class has more method