# where does spring boot set proxy as CGLib

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-aop, cglib

I use @Aspect in my spring boot project. I don't have to manually set @EnableAspectJAutoProxy because spring boot sets it automatically.

When I debug to to aspect class, it shows it as CGLib proxy

```
MyTestAspect$$EnhancerBySpringCGLib$$xxxxxxxx@1234
```

But @EnableAspectJAutoProxy has default proxyTargetClass = false, meaning JDK dynamic is default. Where does SpringBoot set it to true?

**Updated**:

spring.aop.proxy-target-class = true is used in both classes

TransactionAutoConfiguration.java

AopAutoConfiguration.java

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73231363/3426309

Comment: Yes. Thank you Andrey and kriegaex